After changing the length of a page, why do I have to pause for a split-second before auto-scrolling?
In response to user input, I clear the nodes in a container, then copy some other nodes in. This changes the length of the page.
I wanted to scroll back to the top right after this, so added this:
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });

But it wasn't working. It never scrolled back to the top. Sometimes it scrolled partially, sometimes it didn't do anything. It was inconsistent.
I got to wondering if it was a timing thing, so I added this, after copying the nodes in.
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10));
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });

Sure enough, waiting 1/100th of a second before scrolling makes if work perfectly, every time. I've tried every combination of async/await, and nothing works other than pausing for a split-second before scrolling.
I'm assuming the page is calculating its height, or the required amount of scroll, in the moment before the nodes are copied in? How realistic is that assumption?
Is there some more elegant way to handle this, other than my (ugly) pause?

Without a quick [mre] to play with, is this behavior observed only in a specifoc browser? PS: Instead of pausing some arbitrary amount of ms (10) I would use requestAnimationFrame(yourSnapToTopFn) instead of that await setTimeout.

10ms is almost negligible. maybe the delay comes from re-rendering the page by the browser. what if you scroll to the top before changing the content?

Please demonstrate with a stack snippet.
